# Is there any way for me to check if root has been granted before requesting root, so it can be explained to the user?

Tags: android

I swear I've seen this done in other apps, but I can't think of any examples:

I would like to check if my app has been granted root or not (not request).  If not, I would like to explain what's about to happen BEFORE requesting root (triggering the super user dialogue box).

Is there any way to do this?  The only thing I can think of is to save a preference indicating that they've read the explanation before I check, but that's not ideal.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code:

```
/**
   * Checks if the device is rooted.
   *
   * @return <code>true</code> if the device is rooted, <code>false</code> otherwise.
   */
  public static boolean isRooted() {

    // get from build info
    String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
    if (buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys")) {
      return true;
    }

    // check if /system/app/Superuser.apk is present
    try {
      File file = new File("/system/app/Superuser.apk");
      if (file.exists()) {
        return true;
      }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
      // ignore
    }

    // try executing commands
    return canExecuteCommand("/system/xbin/which su")
        || canExecuteCommand("/system/bin/which su") || canExecuteCommand("which su");
  }

  // executes a command on the system
  private static boolean canExecuteCommand(String command) {
    boolean executedSuccesfully;
    try {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
      executedSuccesfully = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      executedSuccesfully = false;
    }

    return executedSuccesfully;
  }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: How does this check for root priviledges?  By looking for a single particular package?  By looking for the 'su' command?  How about checking if you can create a file in /etc or something that actually REQUIRES root powers.  You're not checking anything that makes any difference.

Comment: if your device is rooted Superuser.apk will exist /system/app/. also, it is checking su command as well. So you will surely get true if you have root privilages

Comment: Feel free to correct me, but as far as I can tell doesn't this check of SU exists (which does not indicate if my app has privileges, only that it's possible to request them), and then execute a SU command (which will request privileges)?  I think this is the same problem presently I'm facing: I don't know if I have rights until I try to use them, and then once I use them it's going to make a user request.  I want to preemptive (if possible); check if I have rights, without requesting them, and if I don't have them, then inform the user what is about to occur before I make the request

Comment: you can simply create a . Txt file in the root dorectory and check if that exists.

Comment: @harvey_slash - Wont that trigger a permissions request though?